# Can not push my local project into bitbucket repository using ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, repository

I am facing some issue. I was trying to push my total project into my bit bucket repository but it failed.its showing me the following message.

```
To https://subhrajyoti@bitbucket.org/subhrajyoti/oditek_project.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://subhrajyoti@bitbucket.org/subhrajyoti/oditek_project.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I was running the following commands in terminal to commit my all project code.first I move to my project directory in local machine.

```
1-git init
2-git add -A
3-git commit -m "Initial Commit"
4-git status
5-git remote add origin https://subhrajyoti@bitbucket.org/subhrajyoti/oditek_project.git
6-git push -u origin master
```

Here I need to push all my project code into the single repository means i have the repository name `oditek_project` and i want to my multiple projects (`i.e-project1,project2.....`) into this repository. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: It's git problem. The remote repo has different commits then your local one. You need to pull first and then push

Answer (score 2):

When you create a new repository on BitBucket, it creates a REAME file. So before you can push, you have to pull it first.

Just use git pull first like:

```
git pull -u origin master
```

After this you can push your changes

```
git push -u origin master
```

PS: When you use git, just read the hints and you can find the solution in various cases.